# https with url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

When I enable https on my website, the url rewriting doesn't work ( not found ... )
My htaccess:

```
# URL Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #  Full path to your site
    #
    RewriteBase /           

    # 301 redirect if missing www.
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.% {HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(static/|ajax\.php) - [F,L,NC]

    # 301 redirect if missing trailing slash
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    #  Rules
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?do=/$1

</IfModule>
```

How can I enable https with url rewriting ?

Comment: Show `VirtualHost` entry for SSL site

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *
    ServerAlias *
    Redirect / https://www.communo.fr/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                OptionIndexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `AllowOverride None` in `<Directory /var/www/>` entry which means .htaccess isn't enabled.

To enable .htaccess change that to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

And restart Apache server.

Answer (score -1):

You need to uncomment the lines first I think.